# Several asynchronous processes invoked as a single function

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I need to write a function in swift with a workflow process like this:

1. Call a ViewController to get data
2. Call a web service to perform a calculation
3. Call another web service to persist data

The three processes are asynchronous.

The user calls this process, with code like this:

```
 Get_Calc_And_Save_Data( self, closure: {(error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error==nil {
                print("OPERATION OK")
            } else {
                print("OPERATION ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        })
```

How should I write the processes?
Should I use GCD?

Comment: Cannot get what's the question...

Comment: Hi. Read about `NSOperation` [Apple NSoperations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/). You should create a three operations and set dependency with appropriate order.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can (and there's no should) use any approach, is there any specific question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use several completion handlers along with Booleans to check whether each of the functions have finished like so:

```
func singleMethodToCall(completion: () -> ()) {
    var methodOneFinished = false
    var methodTwoFinished = false
    var methodThreeFinished = false
    asyncMethodOne { () -> () in
        methodOneFinished = true
        if methodOneFinished && methodTwoFinished && methodThreeFinished {
            completion()
        }
    }

    asyncMethodTwo { () -> () in
        methodTwoFinished = true
        if methodOneFinished && methodTwoFinished && methodThreeFinished {
            completion()
        }
    }

    asyncMethodThree { () -> () in
        methodThreeFinished = true
        if methodOneFinished && methodTwoFinished && methodThreeFinished {
            completion()
        }
    }
}


func asyncMethodOne(completion: () -> ()) {
    //Do Stuff
    completion()
}

func asyncMethodTwo(completion: () -> ()) {
    //Do Stuff
    completion()
}

func asyncMethodThree(completion: () -> ()) {
    //Do Stuff
    completion()
}


singleMethodToCall { () -> () in
    print("All three methods have finishsed")
}
```